# Return modified version of stateful function in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm working on an assignment from one of my CS courses and got kinda stuck.

The assignment is to create a message-oriented implementation of associative arrays. These arrays should understand (among others) the following messages:

- `cdr`: returns an *associative array* that contains the current array without the first pair, or an empty array if the array is empty
- `cons`: expects a pair `(key value)` as an argument and generates a new *associative array* by prepending the given key-value-pair to the current array

Basically, the associative array is a list of pairs like `((a 1) (b 7) (c 4) (a 6) (c 5) (d 4) (b 2))` where the characters are the keys and the integers are the values in this case.

To implement the message-oriented style, we should use a `dispatch` function that takes two arguments (where the second argument is only used by the messages that understand it).

What I have so far is this:

```lisp
(define (make-empty-as)
    (define (dispatch msg arg)
        (let ((lst '()))
            (cond
                ((eq? msg 'cdr)
                    (cond ((not (null? lst)) (set! lst (cdr lst))))
                    dispatch)
                ((eq? msg 'cons)
                    (cond ((= (length arg) 2) (set! lst (append lst (list arg)))))
                     dispatch)
                ;; other messages ...
                (else (error "Don't understand " msg)))))
    dispatch)
```

To construct the array above, for example, we could do this:

```lisp
(define a1 (make-empty-as))
(define a2 (a1 'cons '(b 2)))
(define a3 (a2 'cons '(d 4)))
(define a4 (a3 'cons '(c 5)))
(define a5 (a4 'cons '(a 6)))
(define a6 (a5 'cons '(c 4)))
(define a7 (a6 'cons '(b 7)))
(define a8 (a7 'cons '(a 1)))
;; a8 should now have the list ((a 1) (b 7) (c 4) (a 6) (c 5) (d 4) (b 2))
(a8 'cdr 'dummy) ;; should be the list ((b 7) (c 4) (a 6) (c 5) (d 4) (b 2))
```

My problem is the two functions that should return an associative array again.
My approach to return `dispatch` again does not work because this does not keep the modifications I did to `lst`.
Coming from object-oriented languages I tried to find a way to modify the instance variable `lst` and return "myself" (i.e. the modified version of the "object") which would be the function that is currently evaluated(?). Googling around did not bring up anything helpful, unfortunately.

So, the question is if there actually is a way to achieve this or if not if there's another way that I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Right now you have wrapped the `let` expression with a `define` form; what if you instead wrapped the `let` expression _around_ the `define` form so that `dispatch` closes over `lst`?

Comment: That actually does the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness: [@ad absurdum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6879826/ad-absurdum)'s comment was actually the solution for my problem.
However, the approach of simply wrapping the `let` around the `define` resulted in only one "object" being modified by the `cons` messages. I.e. changing the code to this

```lisp
(define (make-empty-as)
    (let ((lst '()))
        (define (dispatch msg arg)
            (cond
                ((eq? msg 'cdr)
                    (cond ((not (null? lst)) (set! lst (cdr lst))))
                    dispatch)
                ((eq? msg 'cons)
                    (cond ((= (length arg) 2) (set! lst (append (list arg) lst))))
                     dispatch)
                ((eq? msg 'print) (display lst) (newline)) ;; added for debugging
                (else (error "Don't understand " msg))))
        dispatch))
```

and running

```lisp
(define a1 (make-empty-as))
(a1 'print 'dummy)
(define a2 (a1 'cons '(b 2)))
(a2 'print 'dummy)
(define a3 (a2 'cons '(d 4)))
(a3 'print 'dummy)
(define a4 (a3 'cons '(c 5)))
(a4 'print 'dummy)
(define a5 (a4 'cons '(a 6)))
(a5 'print 'dummy)
(define a6 (a5 'cons '(c 4)))
(a6 'print 'dummy)
(define a7 (a6 'cons '(b 7)))
(a7 'print 'dummy)
(define a8 (a7 'cons '(a 1)))
(a8 'print 'dummy)
(a1 'print 'dummy)
```

resulted in the following output

```lisp
() ;; a1
((b 2)) ;; a2
((d 4) (b 2)) ;; a3
((c 5) (d 4) (b 2)) ;; a4
((a 6) (c 5) (d 4) (b 2)) ;; a5
((c 4) (a 6) (c 5) (d 4) (b 2)) ;; a6
((b 7) (c 4) (a 6) (c 5) (d 4) (b 2)) ;; a7
((a 1) (b 7) (c 4) (a 6) (c 5) (d 4) (b 2)) ;; a8
((a 1) (b 7) (c 4) (a 6) (c 5) (d 4) (b 2)) ;; a1
```

meaning all of `a1` to `a8` actually represented the same "object".

But the assignment actually wanted `cons` and `cdr` to return **copies** of the associative arrays. Therefore, I simply added a `copy` message that copies the internal `lst` from another object's `lst` and changed `cons` and `cdr` to return new associative arrays:

```lisp
(define (make-empty-as)
    (let ((lst '()))
        (define (dispatch msg arg)
            (cond
                ((eq? msg 'cdr)
                    (cond
                        ((not (null? lst)) ((make-empty-as) 'copy (cdr lst)))
                        (else (make-empty-as))))
                ((eq? msg 'cons)
                    (cond
                        ((= (length arg) 2) ((make-empty-as) 'copy (append (list arg) lst)))
                        (else (make-empty-as))))
                ((eq? msg 'print) (display lst) (newline))
                ((eq? msg 'copy)
                    (cond
                        ((list? arg) (set! lst arg))
                        (else (set! lst '())))
                    dispatch)
                (else (error "Don't understand " msg))))
        dispatch))
```

Running

```lisp
(define a1 (make-empty-as))
(a1 'print 'dummy)
(define a2 (a1 'cons '(b 2)))
(a2 'print 'dummy)
(define a3 (a2 'cons '(d 4)))
(a3 'print 'dummy)
(define a4 (a3 'cons '(c 5)))
(a4 'print 'dummy)
(define a5 (a4 'cons '(a 6)))
(a5 'print 'dummy)
(define a6 (a5 'cons '(c 4)))
(a6 'print 'dummy)
(define a7 (a6 'cons '(b 7)))
(a7 'print 'dummy)
(define a8 (a7 'cons '(a 1)))
(a8 'print 'dummy)
(a1 'print 'dummy)
```

again now gives the desired result

```lisp
() ;; a1
((b 2)) ;; a2
((d 4) (b 2)) ;; a3
((c 5) (d 4) (b 2)) ;; a4
((a 6) (c 5) (d 4) (b 2)) ;; a5
((c 4) (a 6) (c 5) (d 4) (b 2)) ;; a6
((b 7) (c 4) (a 6) (c 5) (d 4) (b 2)) ;; a7
((a 1) (b 7) (c 4) (a 6) (c 5) (d 4) (b 2)) ;; a8
() ;; a1
```

Thanks, again to [@ad absurdum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6879826/ad-absurdum) for nudging me in the right direction.